# Does Eclipse have a way to detect variable name collisions between different scopes?

Tags: java, eclipse, scope, collision-detection

I am using Eclipse 3.5.2 to do my Android Java programming.  I just got bit by a bug that I caused by accidentally declaring a variable in a private method that had the same name as a Class level variable.  Does Eclipse have a "lint" style utility or some function to detect variable names that overlap across scopes?

-- roschler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Eclipse 3.5 you can find it here:

`Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Name shadowing and conflicts`

I don't keep around older installs of Eclipse, but I'm sure 3.2 has it in a similar location.

Comment: My fault.  I meant version 3.5.2.  Fixed it in my post.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn it into either a warning or an error:

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Name shadowing and conflicts

You may have to update your eclipse though, 3.2 is ancient (not sure if it already had that feature).

Comment: My fault.  I meant version 3.5.2.  Fixed it in my post.  Thanks for the reply.